# What does it mean to have a synchronized block on a different monitor than 'this' instance?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following piece of code. It has two objects, namely *MultiThreadingTest*, and the *ThreadB* object. When we say **synchronized(b)**, what does it mean exactly? Can the 'main' thread get a lock on b before ThreadB finishes it's execution? I can't understand the significance of **monitor object** in the synchronized block.

```
 package threads;

    class MultiThreadingTest
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            ThreadB b = new ThreadB();
            b.setName("Thread B");
            b.start();
            synchronized(b)     
            {
                System.out.println("Current thread : "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());          
                try
                {
                    System.out.println("Waiting for b to complete...");
                    b.wait();
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   
                System.out.println("Total = "+b.total );
            }

        }
    }

    class ThreadB extends Thread
    {
        int total;
        public void run()
        {
            synchronized(this)
            {
                System.out.println("Current thread : "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
                {
                    total = total + i;
                }
                notify();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`synchronized(this)` means that you won't be able to enter this block of code if another thread is inside a block of code that is also synchronized on the object referenced by `this`.

`synchronized(b)` means that you won't be able to enter this block of code if another thread is inside a block of code that is also synchronized on the object referenced by `b`.

They thus do the exact same thing. The only difference is the object that is used to lock.

Note that waiting, synchronizing and notifying on an object of type Thread is a really really bad idea. It confuses things, and will lead to unwanted behavior because other methods (join() for example) also use the Thread as a monitor.

Comment: That partly answers my question. Please explain whether the main class can obtain the lock on ThreadB while ThreadB is executing its run(). Why do we have to call wait() on b if we have already synchronized on b in the main()?

Comment: No, it can't, since the body of the run() method is synchronized on the same object (this) as the main method (b). That is implied by my answer. The call to b.wait() allows releasing the lock, in order for the thread B to be able to run. But I repeat: that is bad, bad code. It doesn't use wait() and notify() properly, has race conditions, has bad practices. Don't take that as an example.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. b.start() will make the thread named "Thread B" a different thread of execution, and execute it's run() method. Thread B will be having a lock on b in this case, which means it will compute the total, and notify() the main thread to become runnable. The main will enter the synchronized(b) block and print the total. What is the need to call the wait() then? If we skip the notify() and wait(), why does it not work?
EDIT: Does that mean main can(in some situations)  acquire the lock on b before ThreadB can?

Comment: Starting a thread doesn't execute its run() method immediately. The main thread can continue to execute before the run() method of the new thread executes. You have no guarantee over the order of execution. The posted code assumes that the main thread enters the synchronized block before thread B enters its own synchronized block. But that's an incorrect assumption, that might very well turn false. That's the race condition I was mentioning.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This clarifies a lot of doubts which I had regarding synchronization and locks. Also, I will improve this code as I learn more about multi-threading(I'm a beginner in Java).

Comment: @Manas as a general rule: don't use wait(), notify(), notifyAll(). Use higher-level abstractions like Semaphore, Locks, CountDownLatch.

Answer (score 7):

Think of it like the child's game, whoever holds the [whatever object] gets to speak. Whoever holds the monitor object gets to execute in computing terms.

The monitor is the object you are locking upon, at any given time, only one thread accesses code protected by a synchronization block per monitor object. The object itself is arbitrary and doesn't hold much weight onto synchronization (though you have to watch out for reassigning variables as well as `null` references). Also, JB Nizet raises a good point here on synchronizing on a `Thread` object since many internal VM methods do that, you can cause bazaar, hard to detect bugs and deadlocks.

Two threads entering different synchronization blocks locking on different monitors will execute **concurrently**, analogous to two separate groups of people playing/enacting the "who ever holds to xxx gets to speak" game. Locking on `this` is just a convenient way to manifest a single lock synchronization without creating additional lock objects.

In your case, `ThreadB b` is the same object pointed to as `this` from within the `ThreadB` class meaning that only one thread can enter any of your defined synchronization blocks at once. The order is highly dependent on which thread ran first, the thread scheduler and even the underlying system.

The main reason for monitor objects is so that complex thread-safety mechanisms can be realized. Imagine a system where every synchronization block is single thread access (i.e. at any time, any thread enters a synchronization block will hold every other thread in the whole VM trying to enter a sync block) not only will this cause a massive performance slowdown, it just doesn't make sense. Why should two unrelated application modules lock on each other if they share no data and never interact?

The solution of course is to have one module use one (or several) monitor objects that are unrelated/unassociated with the other module, so both can execute concurrently independent of each other (assuming this is the desired behavior).

To further clarify, you could write:

```
class MultiThreadingTest{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ThreadB b = new ThreadB();
        b.setName("Thread B");
        b.start();

        synchronized(b.lock){
            System.out.println("Current thread : "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());   

            try{
                System.out.println("Waiting for b to complete...");
                b.lock.wait();
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("Total = " + b.total );
        }

    }
}

class ThreadB extends Thread{
    public final Object lock = new Object();

    int total;

    public void run(){
        synchronized(lock){
            System.out.println("Current thread : "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
                total = total + i;
            }

            lock.notify();
        }
    }
}
```

to **exactly** the same effect as the code you've used (even better, since it resolves the conflict with Thread.join() and other methods).

Comment: You have explained the usage of synchronized(this). I asked about the usage of synchronized(b), or in other words, synchronizing on a third-party object in a class other than the third-party class.

Comment: @Manas _"The object itself is arbitrary and doesn't hold much weight onto synchronization"_. As long as `b == this` equals `true` (from within ThreadB), you're talking about the same monitor, causing **exclusive** access to the protected code. Synchronization on all objects behave the same (excluding potential internal VM conflicts) whether this object belongs to the class or even a index in an array from a class from a different package.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, no. The 'this' object within the run() method and the 'b' object in the main() method are the same.

Hence it would not be possible for the 'main' thread to acquire the lock until the thread completes execution.

Also the [notify()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify()) within the run() method seems to be redundant in this case since its at the end of the method and the lock on the monitor would be relinquished any how.

PS: Do look around for similar questions that may already have been asked in the forum. They may help in providing additional understanding.

Comment: No! The `notify()` is required. A call to `wait()` actually **releases** the lock until a corresponding `notify()` or `notifyAll()` is called or the thread is interrupted (though admittedly random wakeups can occur, but shouldn't be relied on). Without the `notify()` the main thread will block forever, waiting until some thread wakes it. In fact OP's code is prone to deadlock should ThreadB hold the lock first, notifying before the actual wait.

Comment: @CPUTerminator actually, if I'm not mistaken, ThreadB will call notifyAll() on itself when it stops running, which will wake up the main thread. So that would work, by accident. But I agree with the deadlock part. This code is crappy.

Comment: @JBNizet Is that as part of the internal mechanism to facilitate `join()`? Well, if so, I didn't think of that, thank you. Never actually looked at the internals of `Thread` just kinda assumed they were all native methods hidden away.

Comment: Yes: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28long%29